# Django xml for flash?

Tags: django, django-templates

how ill write a xml file for use with flash?, Django Doc dont have nothing about XML (just for Feeds)....

Tutorial?

Thansk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting the start of the [Django documentation on templates](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#templates):

> A template is simply a text file. It can generate any text-based format (HTML, XML, CSV, etc.).

Your view will look something like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def your_view(request)
    context_data = {'extra': stuff}
    return render_to_response('your_xml_template.xml', context_data,
                              mimetype='application/xml')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can even use one of the handy [generic views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/generic-views/#ref-generic-views) to easily generate XML using data from one of your models. Something like this could go into your **urls.py** file:

```
urlpatterns = ('django.views.generic.list_detail',
    (r'^mymodel-(?P<object_id>\d+).xml$', 'object_detail', {'queryset': MyModel.objects.all(),
                                                            'template_name': 'your_xml_template.xml',
                                                            'mimetype': 'application/xml'}),
   (... more url patterns ...),
)
```

All you have to do is write the XML template.

Answer (score -1):

Or you can directly respond using a string, without templates.

```
def view(request):
   return HttpResponse("<xml></xml>",mimetype="application/xml")
```